# Display woocommerce product attribute term description in additional info tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize the woocommerce template **single-product / product-attributes.php** so it will display the term description if not empty on the product tabs. For example i have a product attribute condition with values "excellent", "good", etc and for each term there is a description. I want to display the description of each of those terms in product tab additional info.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
    return;
}
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
            
            <td> /** display here the description **/ </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: I tried the variable $product_attribute['description'] and doesnt work. I checked the woocomerce code and i think this $product_attributes array has only name and value for each term. I want to access the description of each term. This template has access to the global $product variable i think.